# Unity doesn't recognize Length Method

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm completly new to Unity and C# and I have the following problem. I just want to use the .Length method on an Array. MonoDevelop doesn't recognize the .Length method.
It's probably a really stupid question, but I really don't know how to deal with this, I just don't have any experience with this stuff.

I'm using Unity 2017.1.0f1: on Ubuntu.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform thePlatformGenerator;
private Vector3 theplatformGeneratorStartPoint;

public Transform thePlayer;
private Vector3 thePlayerStartPoint;

private PlatformDestructor[] platformList;


// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    theplatformGeneratorStartPoint = thePlatformGenerator.position;
    thePlayerStartPoint = thePlayer.position;

}

public void RestartGame(){
    thePlayer.position = thePlayerStartPoint;
    thePlatformGenerator.position = theplatformGeneratorStartPoint;
    platformList = FindObjectsOfType<PlatformDestructor> ();
    for (int x = 0; x < platformList.Length; x++) {
        Destroy(platformList[x]);
    }
}
```

If anyone could help me, I would be really thankful.

Comment: i think maybe you need to cast the result of FindObjectsOfType. So like this: platformList = FindObjectsOfType<PlatformDestructor> () as PlatformDestructor[];

Comment: MonoDevelop does not recognize it (does not suggest it), or you have a compiler error in Unity ?

Comment: It's marked red by Monodevelope and read as 0 by Unity.

Comment: MonoDevelop can be "capricious". If you don't have compiler error in Unity, it's fine. If `platformList.Length` returns 0, then `FindObjectsOfType` is not able to find **active** gameobjects holding the `PlatformDestructor` script.